# Share data from Layout to RenderBody

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to share data from my main _Layout to the views rendered by RenderBody.

I tried to use a ViewBag initialized in "Shared/_Layout" but it doesn't work. However, I noticed that this ViewBag can be used in partials but not in the views displayed by @RenderBody.

Example _Layout:

```
PageData["XX"] = "myValue";
ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.XX= "myValue";
Page.XX= "myValue"; 
ViewBag.XX= "myValue";
ViewContext.ViewData["XX"] = "myValue";

<body>
    @Html.Partial("_MyPartial") // Everything has the correct value in the partial

    <main class="content">
        @RenderBody() // Everything is null in that view
    </main>
</body>
```

I tried with ViewBag.Property, ViewData["Property"], Page.Property and PageData["Property"] but they are all null in the view rendered by RenderBody.
It seems that because the Layout is the last element compiled.

I don't want to use any code. Everything needs to be in the view, do something pretty similar to my example above. It must be in the layout because the value I want to share is defined by the user through the CMS. It means that this layout is used by static page but also views rendered by controller.

My question is: How I can give/share data from the _Layout to my views rendered by RenderBody()?

Comment: Do you populate your ViewBag in your controller?

Comment: The ViewBag is only populated in the _Layout. That's why I also try PageData[""] to give data from parent page to child page without using the controller.

Comment: ViewBag needs to be populated in the controller, any particular reason you are doing it in Layout?

Comment: Yes, it is because I don't necessarily hit a controller to display a view using this _Layout

Comment: How can you not hit a controller!!?

Comment: It is because the website is a MVC app working also with static page created through a CMS. All the pages are using the same _Layout, that's why I want to be able to share data (ViewBag or something else)

Comment: be careful of [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). it is when you ask X, but your actual problem is Y

Comment: I don't think that having -2 it is fair but okay. Sharing data between views is, in my opinion, a good question. So please @Mark, develop.

Comment: why would you think that its me who do the downvote? I said 'be careful' I didnt say 'IT IS'.

Comment: It is not for the downvote, it is for xy problem. I tried to write my question the simpler as possible but also with enough info to understand the problem. I read your article and basically, I wouldn't ask correctly. It is not a critic, I'm just interested by your comment and why you wrote it. What did you not understand in my question?

Comment: it is a pretty good practice to also include your problem's background. for example, why you only want to declare your viewbag in the layout? is it because its reading some config or some Database? how do you use the viewbag in your Views inside the `renderbody()`? is it only in some of the Views? or is it in every Views? why dont you want to create another public/shared Views with that viewbag. and you can just render it?

Comment: @Mark Thanks for your comment, I'm going to edit my question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your Layout :

```
@ViewContext.Controller.ViewBag.Test= "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

> How I can give/share data to my views rendered by RenderBody()?

Controllers are responsible for preparing the data (model, ViewBag, TempData, etc) and handing it over to Views.

You could also look into [filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) for preparing the data.

---

You need to populate your ViewBag in your Controller:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // populate your ViewBag
        ViewBag.myValue = "some text";
    }
}
```

And then in your View/PartialView you can use it like this:

*MyPartialView.cshtml*

```
<label>@ViewBag.myValue</label>
```

Comment: Thanks, Hooman but as I said in my comment, I don't necessarily hit a controller to display the view. I edited my post to explain that I want to share data without using any code in back-end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can used viewBag in your partials view. When call viewBag in razor file(***.cshtml***)
you must be return a partial view for display.

Answer (score -1):

ViewBag and ViewData is view-specific, so they're emptied whenever you hit a different View/Action. Try checking this link http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications for more info.

Try using TempData for that effect - http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc